# SSIS comparing Binary columns using Conditional Split

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I need to compare two varbinary columns using SSIS Conditional Split component.

I cannot use the == operator with varbinary.

What is the best way to compare two varbinary columns.

Have tried converting to TEXT datatype but this gives me various problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use a Script Component, and compare the varbinary columns using VB.NET or C#?  You could then assign a value to a new column in the data flow that lets you identify if they were identical.  The Conditional Split could then use the new column as the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Two Columns are compared in Script Transformation Component , But do not know how to columns with Binary DataTypes are compared.

If anybody answers how binary values can be compared in Scrit component..you will have ur answer.